# infinitive usage in complex sentence

Tags: infinitives

which one is correct?

An evaluation of the Cronicle interface suggests that Cronicle helped the participants **to** find data accurately.

or

An evaluation of the Cronicle interface suggests that Cronicle helped the participants find data accurately.

Answer (score 1):

Right. First of all, the word "chronicle" comes from Greek and is spelled accordingly. The god Chronos and all.

Now, I've read your sentence four times, and I only have a very vague idea of what actually happened there. Which is unacceptable. You've got to rewrite it.

Did the participants take part in the evaluation? Or did they participate in something else? Who conducted the evaluation? What does "evaluation" even mean in this context?

Can one find data inaccurately?

**The "to" seems to be superfluous**, but the rest is just wrong. You're trying to hard, that's what. Don't try to sound technical or sophisticated: just explain what happened there. Simplify. Break it down into three parts. Like this:

1. Participants (where did they come from? were they paid?)
2. The evaluation process (was it a test?)
3. Results (definite, not foggy)

Oh, and by the way, the results of a test should demonstrate, or prove conclusively, not suggest. You need to be certain, not vague. In my opinion, anyway.

Comment: Hi, Ricky. The OP is specifically asking about the usage of "to-infinitive" which is a duplicate and soon-to-be closed.

Comment: I just want to know whether the use of to is correct or not :)

Comment: @Rathony - Hmm. Does that mean that 500 points will be stripped from my rep as soon as they close it?

Comment: @SamiulAlamAnik: It is technically correct, but quite superfluous. Don't use it.

Comment: I don't think so and I sincerely hope not. I just wanted to give you a heads-up if you don't mind.